# Prove that if $a_n$ is strictly decreasing, $a_n \rightarrow 0$ and $n_0$ is even, then $ \sum_{n=n_0}^{+ \infty } a_n>0$

Tags: real-analysis

I have a problem with this task because I don't know how much I must write here.
If   $a_n$ is strictly decreasing and $a_n \rightarrow 0$, then I know that $a_n$ is limited from below by $0$ and all words of $a_n$ are $>0$, because if $a_n<0$ and $a_n$ strictly decreasing, then $a_n \rightarrow - \infty$, but it is contradiction. 
If I know that all $a_n$ is $>0$ (because I prove it), then I know that $a_{n_0}+a_{n_1}+a_{n_2}+...= \sum_{n=n_0}^{+ \infty } a_n>0$. However I am afraid that this is not enough evidence. Moreover I don't know for what purpose the information is given that $ a_ {n_0} $ is even.

Comment: The information that $n_0$ (or $a_{n_0}$ as in the body of the question?) is even is irrelevant. Did you cite the problem statement correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption that if $\exists n\in \mathbf{N}$ such that $a_n<0$ then that $\{a_n\}$ is strictly decreasing should imply that $a_n\rightarrow -\infty$ is false. Consider $a_n = -1+\frac{1}{n}$ which is strictly decreasing but $a_n\rightarrow -1$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Instead if $a_{n_0}<0$ for some $n_{0}$ then you can conclude that $a_n\not\rightarrow 0$. Do you see how? Consider some neighborhood of $0$ which does not contain any $a_n$ with $n>n_0$.

The fact that $n_0$ is even is immaterial. If $a_n>0$ for every $n$ then

$$\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty}a_n>0$$

Comment: Yes, you have right that I had a mistake in reasoning regarding $a_{n_0}<0$. Thank's for help